# Python Socket utf-8 decoding

Tags: python, sockets, http, utf-8, decode

I want to get the response of a GET request into a string, and i came up with the following code:

```js
import socket

target_host = "www.google.com"

target_port = 80  # create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# connect the client
s.connect((target_host, target_port))

# send some data
request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:%s\r\n\r\n" % target_host
s.send(request.encode("utf-8"))
full_msg = ""

# Prevent recv() function to stop the script to wait until  it receives more data, even if there is no more.
s.settimeout(1)
flag = True

while flag:
    # receive some data
    try:
        response = s.recv(4096)
        full_msg = full_msg + str(response)
        print("Adding msg")
    except Exception as e:
        print(full_msg)
        flag = False
        print(e)

print("Loop ended")
print(type(full_msg))
```

The thing is, when i try do decode the response in s.recv(4096) replacing it with this code:

```js
response = s.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
```

I get the following exception:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 1025: invalid continuation byte
```

I don't know how to fix this as i can't modify the characters i get from the response and i need to delete the " b' " character which messes up my full_msg string if i don't decode it each time in the loop.

Also, in the docs it says that the .recv() method returns a string, but i seem to be getting a byte-like object. Any idea is welcomed and i am also open to know any ways my code could be improved.

Comment: any reason not to use `urllib`?

Answer (score 0):

Per the data in your response, `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`.  The response is not UTF-8.  `.decode('iso-8859-1')` instead.  Better yet use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/):

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.encoding)
# print(r.text)    # already decoded with r.encoding
# print(r.content) # byte string of original encoded data
# print(r.json())  # If the response is JSON data, This loads the data.
```